# Is it possible to extract gray scale images using image_view?

Tags: rosbag, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros messages which contains imaged data of type 16UC1. But image_view seems to extract image of type RGB8 only. Is it possible to make it convert 8UC1 and 16UC1 types?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199868/is-it-possible-to-extract-gray-scale-images-using-image_view?/) by [shravan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21096/shravan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how much effort it would be to modify `image_view`. But you could try [rqt_image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_image_view) which as far as I remember has a conversion for that image encoding.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1